# Docker and SQL Server Linux - Error 9002. The transaction log for database master is full due to NOTHING

Tags: sql-server, docker, virtualbox, dockerfile, sql-server-linux

I use Docker without Hyper-V with VirtualBox and Docker VM on Windows 10 Home edition.

I have the following Docker build file:

```
FROM repositoryname/mssql-server-linux:test-db

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .  /usr/src/app

# start sql, setup db
RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & sleep 15s && \
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P pass -d master -i /usr/src/app/setup_db_1.sql && \
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P pass -d master -i /usr/src/app/setup__db_2.sql
```

Right now MS SQL Server fails during startup with the following error:

```
Error 9002. The transaction log for database master is full due to NOTHING
```

Is there anything I can do (for example add some instructions to my Docker build file) in order to prevent this error?

Also, I found the similar topic here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca65a3e2-2f30-4641-a7ea-d3998c8dd8a7/the-transaction-log-for-database-master-is-full-due-to-nothing-during-updade?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade but unfortunately without the proper answer right now.

Comment: Your docker builds fine and run has a issue? Can you post `docker inspect <containerid>` for the failed container on http://pastebin.com?

Comment: Yes, the docker builds fine but run has the mentioned issue. This issue appears on the latest rebuild from the official microsoft/mssql-server-linux image

Comment: I think you issue issue would be this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes. `Changing the volume from within the Dockerfile: If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I didn't get it but the biggest my concern is that everything was working fine before the last update...

Comment: Can you use a older tag to test it ?

Comment: This is my biggest issue :( Unfortunately, we didn't  save the previous tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157201/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-alexanoid).